# HOW TO: Restrict url to specific IP using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to block a specific URL that looks like www.domain.com/admin/login/? using the htaccess and grant permission to access the url only for specific IP addresses.

We have already tried this and it partially works. The "?" in the URL seems to be giving problem. When I include the ? in the htaccess along with the URL as shown below, it won't work the way it is required to work. What am i doing wrong here?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule admin/login/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

[Existing htaccess](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3201969/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-15%20at%206.43.02%20PM.png)

UPDATE:
I’ve a custom CMS and it doesn't have a typical tree stucture, i.e. `http://www.mysite.com/folder` doesn't correspond to `/var/www/folder`, and in fact `http://www.mysite.com/folder` doesn't have a single file or directory representation at all. Thus there is no corresponding .htaccess file for `/folder`. I don't see how to attach a URL instead of a directory to the rewrite rule. Here are the rewrite concepts I have been playing with:

Will this work? I found this online:

```
<Location /folder>
Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

UPDATE#2:
The problem has been solved. The problem was due to the reason that I was using Cloudflare. This made all the request to the url from cloudflare. Upon installing mod_cloudflare on the server and using the below script, I was successfully able to block access to public allowing only specified IP's.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)admin(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule .* / [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Getting internal server error for the <Location> directive

Comment: What kind of "internal error"? `<Location>` was designed for that.

Answer (score 3):

This rule should work for blocking of that URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule ^admin/login/? - [F,NC]
```

**UPDATE:** Place this code in `/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule ^login/? - [F,NC]
```

Comment: It is not working. The ? is actually part of the URL. Should I escape this using `\?` ?

Comment: Still the same. Not working with the updated answer. The URL is in this format. `http://www.website.com/admin/login/?`. When a user types that URL, if their IP is not allowed to view it, then they would be taken to `http://www.website.com`

Comment: It is not blocking at all.

Comment: Ya I was uploading the snapshot. As I'm new here..the system won't allow me to add image. See the link in my answer for the existing .htaccess :)

Comment: Not working. I just did that. I pasted your suggested script right after the existing ReWriteEngine on chunk. Other IP's can still reach the page. :(

Comment: The htaccess is being read. Only this command is not working. I'll try the other recommendation and let you know.

Comment: There is no .htaccess under admin/.htaccess

Comment: Yes. It shows Internal server error when I put crap in my htaccess :)

Comment: You are right. The admin/htaccess is not being read. It is actually empty. Only the master /htaccess is being read. The above command didn't work either.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Didn't work. I'm using a custom CMS. I'm not sure if the dev has some kind of URL rewriting that is not following the file directory structure for URL's.

Comment: thanks a lot for so many recommendations. However, I'm not sure why in my case, this won't work. I'm also checking with my hosting company for help. Meanwhile, do you think of any alternative method using allow, deny?

Comment: I’ve a custom CMS and it doesn't have a typical tree stucture, i.e. http://www.mysite.com/folder doesn't correspond to /var/www/folder, and in fact http://www.mysite.com/folder doesn't have a single file or directory representation at all. Thus there is no corresponding .htaccess file for /folder. I don't see how to attach a URL instead of a directory to the rewrite rule.

Comment: Do you think this would work? `<Location /folder>`
                `Order deny,allow`
                `deny from all`
                `llow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
                `allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
`</Location>`

Comment: @anubhava excellent piece of code, but can you tell me how to block multiple url using this? Like multiple RewriteRule for single RewriteCond? Thanks

Comment: You can use regex alternation like `RewriteRule ^(login|urlA|urlB)`

Answer (score 2):

```
# only allow acces to these urls from white listed IPs
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#the urls that should be checked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/login|/wp-login.php|/wp-admin).*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# or this ip
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# if not fail
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a .htaccess  file to the root directory of the website whose url you want to block.

Add this code in the .htaccess file

```
order deny,allow
allow from (please enter the ip address here to which you want to grant access)
deny from all
```

This should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is a special regex character, so you have to escape it with a backslash: `\?`

Comment: is this correct? `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule admin/login/\?$ / [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

if the url begins with /admin and the remote address is not one of the three listed, send the browser on its merry way.

reference : https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/restrict-urls-starting-with-abc-to-specific-ips-.htaccess-guru

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`Location`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location)?

```
<Location /admin/login>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from xxx.xxx.
    Allow from yyy.yyy.
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code with .htaccess and change IP adress. 123.123.123.123 only can access website, other IP redirect to maintenance.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.123.123.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```