# multilanguage website made with Codeigniter. How can I set permissions to one language only one IP?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, permissions, ip

I have a multilanguage website made with Codeigniter. So urls is like http://example.com/en or http://example.com/es and more...
I need to give permissions only to one people to spanish version. Can I do it with .htaccess?:

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from

The problem is that this way I allow or deny all my site. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with _one people_ ? is this a static ip address oder a loggedin user or what ?

Comment: Just one person, or one IP contection

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794164/how-to-restrict-url-to-specific-ip-using-htaccess